# Excel: Plot a single X and Y coordinate in a static graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to create a coordinate graph where the X and Y axis are in a static 1 to 4 scale and the values do not change. The point to be plotted is gathered from two formulas that calculate the value of the magnitude and the value of the likelihood, so they are constantly changing values. However I want the graph to always display both X and Y axis in a 1 to 4 scale without the point to be plotted affecting the axis in any way (see illustration below).

I have tried using a scatter plot for this. It is similar to what I need, I just need the graph to always display both axis in a 1 to 4 scale, then take the values of magnitude and likelihood, and plot them in the graph.

I know this is probably not rocket science, I just cannot find a definitive answer online.

Here is an example of what I need:

[image: Drawn Example]

Comment: Don't the likelihoods have to be between 0 and 1?

Comment: @help-info.de It's not relevant to the issue, is it?

Comment: right-click on the axis > format axis, under axis options:bounds put 4 in the maximum

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a scatter plot
2. Set the min and max bounds for each axis to 0 and 4 respectively. The default is "auto" so it will choose the axis scale based on the value to be plotted.

Ps. If you use any "volatile" functions like RAND or NOW in your formulae, the value will change and hop around on the graph each time your press F9 (recalculate).